# using code of file upload max size event into simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery/javascript now i have a form in which user can upload multiple files which is working just fine but i need to do alterations to it this is the working code.

```
$('#userFiles').change(function() {
  var combinedSize = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    combinedSize += (this.files[i].size || this.files[i].fileSize);
  }
  if (combinedSize > 104857600) {
    toastr["error"]("Max upload size is 100MB");
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="userFiles" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
```

Now what i want to do is before submitting the check whther the collective files sizes are more than 100 if yes then stop the form from submitting and display an error that you cannot upload more than 100MB now this is the updated code.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#userFiles').change(function() {
    var combinedSize = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      combinedSize += (this.files[i].size || this.files[i].fileSize);
    }
    if (combinedSize > 104857600) {
      toastr["error"]("Max upload size is 100MB");
    }
  });
});
```

My issue is that it using **this** function because it is an event for input change when it comes to form submit i cannot use another event inside it i want the logic to work only on form submit how can i replace **this** with the userFile id attribute? i tried  couple of ways but it is not working.

Comment: You should avoid creating event handlers inside other event handlers.  It's a great way of creating duplicate bindings which will often drive you into issues.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i am trying the loop actually uses this variable due to event how can i pass the input type file instead of this?

Comment: <input  type="file" class="form-control" id="userFiles" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>

Comment: Add that to your question, not as a comment.  Further question.  Why create a change binding in the submit handler at all?  Why not just grab the files and do your check?

Comment: the input type that is actually uploading the file of whom i want to validate that if the size of all files are greater than 100 than error should be displayed

Comment: `$('#userFiles').prop('files')` will get you the files property off of that DOM element.  I don't understand why you need the change event handler at all; in the submit handler that is.

Comment: let me explain to you again the current handler $('#userFiles').change(function() {  it is working fine but it is working independently where as what i want is when the form submits it should check if the total size is greater than 100MB the form should not submit and error should be displayed on front end

Comment: Is your question/problem with the value of `this` within the `change` event?

Comment: yes i dont want to use the change event i have the form submit event already i just wan to use this logic inside the form submit event so that the error is displayed after clicking on submit button right now it just displays the error when file size exceeds because it is an change handler now the problem comes with this how will i refer the  id="userFiles" instead of this ? because i will not be using the change handler inside the form submit handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function validateMaxFileSize() {
  //get the files off of the element
  var files = $('#userFiles').prop('files');
  var combinedSize = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    combinedSize += (files[i].size || files[i].fileSize);
  }
  //return true if the max is exceeded
  return (combinedSize > 104857600);
}

$('#userFiles').change(function() {
  //if the max is exceeded, show toaster
  if (validateMaxFileSize()) {
    toastr["error"]("Max upload size is 100MB");
  }
});

$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  //if the max is exceeded, cancel the submit
  if (validateMaxFileSize()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toastr["error"]("Max upload size is 100MB");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="userFiles" name="userFiles[]" multiple/>
```

Comment: You should also perform the file size check on the server side, as users can always break your javascript. @uneebmeer

Comment: yes the php part is already working in the backend i just thought it would be nice to stop certain user on the client side to save additional load on server :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use a global variable to do this. e.g.

```
var combinedSize = 0;

$('#userFiles').change(function() {
    combinedSize = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      combinedSize += (this.files[i].size || this.files[i].fileSize);
    }

  });

$("form").on("submit", function(e) {


   if (combinedSize > 104857600){
    e.preventDefault();
    toastr["error"]("Max upload size is 100MB");
   }

});
```

remember that this is only client side validation and it is not sufficient! what happens if the users broswer has javascript disabled? The form will still submit and the file will go through. You need to do server side validation to ensure that they do not exceed the file limit. You can set values in a configuration file for maximum file request size . You can use the web.config if you have an asp.net app. You can also check in the server code whether the file size is to big and return a validation message.

Comment: dully noted..:)